# on button click the mails are not getting tagged

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail, gmail-api

- I am trying to build a chrome extension for bulk tagging functionality by using gmail API.
- I am using inboxsdk API for button creation in gmail inbox.
- The button which I am using will be displayed in the gmail tool-bar next to delete button in existing gmail scenario.
- Also for bulk tagging functionality to work on button click I am using gmail API.
- In the sense when we click the button the selected mails should get tagged with the "general" label in gmail inbox.

> I am facing the issue when I am trying to execute the chrome extension
>   at button click means

- After the mails got selected for tagging.
- When I click on the 'General' button for the mails to get tagged with general label.
- At that time the mails are not getting tagged and the error message is
  getting displayed.

[The UI of my present functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZtbj.png)

The error which I am facing on button click is

```
Error logged: ReferenceError: GmailApp is not defined
    at tagLabel (chrome-extension://comojhnglmoikgmlgajalpkdmhkkhdao/contentScript/tag.js:6:13)
    at e.i.onClick [as _activateFunction] (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:96:9933)
    at e.r.value (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:97:9380)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:97:9085)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:21971)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:14725)
    at Object.n.UpdateBarrier.c [as inTransaction] (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:14490)
    at e.push (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:24310)
    at e.handleEvent (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:25004)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:10944)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:31344)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:95:8103) 

Original error stack:
ReferenceError: GmailApp is not defined
    at tagLabel (chrome-extension://comojhnglmoikgmlgajalpkdmhkkhdao/contentScript/tag.js:6:13)
    at e.i.onClick [as _activateFunction] (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:96:9933)
    at e.r.value (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:97:9380)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:97:9085)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:21971)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:14725)
    at Object.n.UpdateBarrier.c [as inTransaction] (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:14490)
    at e.push (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:24310)
    at e.handleEvent (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:25004)
    at eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:10944)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:9:31344)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:95:8103) 

Error logged from:
    at Object.i [as default] (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:74:26373)
    at a (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:95:7900)
    at Function.f.value (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:95:11263)
    at HTMLDivElement.eval (https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js:95:8142) 

Error details: Uncaught error in event listener 

Extension App Ids: [
  {
    "appId": "sdk_mailtag_fd47af3e65"
  }
] 
Sent by App: false 
Session Id: 1448273876180-0.754944005748257 
Extension Id: chrome-extension://comojhnglmoikgmlgajalpkdmhkkhdao/ 
InboxSDK Loader Version: 0.7.9-802f1aa6afeaeaff 
InboxSDK Implementation Version: 0.7.13-1448069038650-cd7978078f7ce7a6
Uncaught ReferenceError: GmailApp is not defined
```

The code of the functionality:

manifest.json:

```
{
"name": "Gmail Extension",
"description": "Extension for tagging",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"minimum_chrome_version": "29",
"background": {
"page": "/background/index.html"
  },
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": [
"https://mail.google.com/*",
"https://inbox.google.com/*"],
"js": ["/libs/inboxsdk.js", "/libs/alertify/alertify.min.js", "/contentScript/tag.js"],
"css": ["/libs/alertify/alertify.default.css", "/libs/alertify/alertify.core.css"],
"run_at": "document_end"
}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["/icons/tag.png", "*"],
"permissions": ["identity", "<all_urls>", "tabs", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "https://accounts.google.com/*", "https://www.googleapis.com/*", "https://mail.google.com/",
"https://inbox.google.com/"],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-Y+2PBkTuXdKc9Mz9jB6CV7zSLRMuViwjLM28phOgupM=' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
"oauth2": {
"client_id": "763145023672-gblto66pc638n485lu08visrvpocfqbs.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scopes": ["https://mail.google.com/",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"]
  }
  }
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Extension for tagging</title>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<script src = "auth.js" </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"></script>
<script src = "/libs/inboxsdk.js" </script>
<script src = "/contentScript/tag.js" </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="authorize-div" style="display: none">
<span>Authorize access to Gmail API</span>
<!--Button for the user to click to initiate auth sequence -->
<button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
Authorize
</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

auth.js:

```
var CLIENT_ID = '763145023672-gblto66pc638n485lu08visrvpocfqbs.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var SCOPES = [
'https://mail.google.com/',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
 ];
function checkAuth() {
gapi.auth.authorize({
'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': true
},
handleAuthResult);
}
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
// Hide auth UI, then load client library.
authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
loadGmailApi();
} else {
// Show auth UI, allowing the user to initiate authorization by
// clicking authorize button.
authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
}
}
function handleAuthClick(event) {
gapi.auth.authorize({
'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES, 'immediate': false
},
handleAuthResult);
return false;
}
function loadGmailApi() {
gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', updateLabel);
}
function updateLabel(){
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.update({
'userId': 'me'
});
request.execute(function(resp) {
    tagLabel()
});
}
```

tag.js:

```
function whenNoneSelected(route) {
  return false;
}
function register(sdk) {
  function tagLabel() {
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("General");
var threads = label.getThreads(); // var threads = GmailApp.getThreads();
for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
//add label "General" for selected threads
threads[i].addLabel(label);
}
      alertify.success('Threads marked as General'); 
  }
  sdk.Toolbars.registerToolbarButtonForList({
    title: 'General',
    section: sdk.Toolbars.SectionNames.INBOX_STATE,
    iconUrl: chrome.extension.getURL('/icons/tag.png'),
    onClick: tagLabel,
    hasDropdown: false,
    hideFor: whenNoneSelected,
    keyboardShortcutHandle: null
  });
}
InboxSDK.load('1', 'sdk_mailtag_fd47af3e65').then(register);
```

Anyone with relevant solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see `GmailApp` in InboxSDK reference, it uses a different model. Apparently you're trying to mix two APIs.

Comment: Yes of-course I am trying to mix both API's. Gmail API for functionality purpose and Inboxsdk for UI purpose.

Comment: I see. Take a look at the [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): you have `GmailAPI` in the background script which is isolated from the content script. Also you can't use inline js in extension pages like the background/popup/options page.

Comment: are you trying to use 'GmailApp'  from Google Apps script ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app

Comment: yes I am trying to use 'GmailApp' from Google Developers site only.